# Setting cutplanes for polygon shape

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Autodesk.Viewing.Markupscore extension to draw a polygon in 3D view in top view (orthographic) [image]

I want to see only those elements which are inside the polygon

For which I am using the cutplanes concept because bounding box logic is taking too long to process.

So Please suggest a way to apply cut planes along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try programmatically cutplanes with an array of vector4s specifying the four sides say:

```
vectorArray.push(new THREE.Vector4 (0.9999999999999998, 0, 0, 0.06520926952362059)) //x,y,z,w
viewer.setCutPlanes(vectorArray)
```

See documentation [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setcutplanes-planes)

Comment: How can I get this Vector4 from the two points of a line in the polygon?
I can convert these two points from client to world, please help me in finding Vector4 from these two Vector3 points.